# Getting double for events in modal when using backbone render

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to render a modal using backbone on click of save button, for the first time if i do any operation it works fine and then I close the modal and click the save again, the modal renders again and now if i do any events on modal they are triggering twice. This iteration increases every time i close and click save again.

This is how I'm rendering the modal on page load:

```
new app.notifyView(this.options.model);
```

Every time I click the save button this will be called.

Comment: Is a new event handler added each time the modal renders?

Comment: What I mean is, for example, is there a new backbone view or something created each time?

Comment: yes, this will create a new view every time

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem called "Zombie Event Handlers". You can read some great details on it here: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Here's the oversimplified explanation: every time you use `new app.myView()`, you create a new instance of your `myView` object (We'll call this one "ViewOne"). ViewOne has its own event handlers. Let's say you close ViewOne, so it's no longer visible, but then make a new instance ("ViewTwo"). ViewTwo now has its own new event handlers AND ViewOne is still alive in the background. When you perform an action, ViewOne's event watchers are still active in memory, along with ViewTwo's, so both are called and the action happens twice. "Weird", you say, "let me just close this view and open a new one." ViewThree adds another set of event handlers in memory, and now you get 3 times the calls. To stop these "zombies" from lumbering around in your memory, you'd need to know how to access each individual instance and pick it off. It's much easier to prevent them from forming in the first place.

The easiest way to handle this is with "handles". Assign your views a unique variable (a "handle" to grab that particular instance of the view with later - like out "ViewOne", "ViewTwo" & "ViewThree" above) when they're created, and make sure that view is closed/gone before reassigning the event handler. There are tons of ways to implement this. If you'll update your question with code I'll gladly offer a solution that will work for your particular situation.

UPDATE:

That's not a lot of code to work with, but here's an idea:

```
app.modal = app.modal || new app.notifyView(this.options.model);
```

This will only create the view once - if it already exists, it will reference the existing handle. Later on, if you want to clear the event handlers manually, you can call the following:

```
function clearHandlers() {
    app.modal.remove();
    app.modal.unbind();
}
```

I'll reiterate that Derick Bailey's awesome explanation on the causes and ways to prevent/fix this issue is well worth the read. The link is still above if you have a few minutes.

Comment: I updated my post with the code i'm using

Comment: Instead of removing the events for modal can we directly remove the events for view itself. app.notifyView.remove()???

Comment: No, because `app.notifyView()` is not an instance - it's a definition describing the object you create when you use the `new` keyword. The event handlers are tied to that instance, not the `Backbone.View` itself.

Comment: I added some detail to my explanation above - see if that helps it make more sense. :)